# jQuery "Cycle" plugin causing content to not center, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to use the jQuery "Cycle" plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to rotate testimonials located within `<span>`s ... however the plugin is causing my content to not be centered. Yesterday morning someone here pointed out the `<span>` elements are being absolutely positioned by the plugin: `$slides.css({position: 'absolute', top:0, left:0}).hide()`

I don't know JS and I'm still working on my HTML/CSS, so I was hoping someone here knew a fix for this and could help me. If not oh well :/

I've tried adding `left:50%` and although it centers, the slide is broken and all my `<span>`s appear at once.

[Edit]

Here's the HTML & CSS:

```
<div class="slideshow">
<span style="font-size:12px; color:#333333; font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;">Hi</span>
<span style="font-size:12px; color:#333333; font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;">Goodbye</span>
</div><br />

.slideshow {
width:940px;
height:64px;
text-align:center;
background-image:url(../images/quotes.png);
}
```

Alone, everything works as planned. Then I add the jQuery/Cycle plugin:

```
// set position and zIndex on all the slides
    $slides.css({position: 'absolute', top:0, left:0}).hide().each(function(i) {
        var z;
        if (opts.backwards)
            z = first ? i <= first ? els.length + (i-first) : first-i : els.length-i;
        else
            z = first ? i >= first ? els.length - (i-first) : first-i : els.length-i;
        $(this).css('z-index', z)
    });
```

This is what screws it all up. As is, the `<span>` s are shown one at a time and fade in and out like they're supposed to, except the text isn't centered anymore due to the absolute positioning. So I changed `left:0` to `left:50%` - wha la! Problem solved text is centered, except NOW the spans are all shown at the same time and there's no fading in/out.

Comment: I suggest you post up more code, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I posted more as asked. Please tell me how to fix this :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the code this isn't easy to call but I assume the testimonials are within a block element of some sort. If you apply `position:relative` to that element the absolutely positioned `<span>`s will be contained within. You shouldn't really apply any positioning styles to the spans themselves - rather leave that to the plugin.

Hope that helps

---

**EDIT**

Okay try this:

```
.slideshow {
    width:940px;
    height:64px;
    background-image:url(../images/quotes.png);
    position:relative;
    }

.slideshow span {
    display:block;
    }
```

You may need to manually set the width of the `<spans>`s as well to match the width of the `div.slideshow`

Comment: Position relative doesn't help, thanks though. I've added the actual sources... maybe you can look at see what needs fixed.

Comment: Genius! It worked, I had to set the width/height to keep it centered, but it worked! Thank you :)